# wxWidgets multiline in wxlistctrl header

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm trying to insert a Multiline text in the wxlistctrl header under Ms Windows.

The wxWidgets library does not natively support the multiline text, so i tried to use istrunction like:

HWND listView   = (HWND)(m_listCtrl->GetHWND());
HWND header     = ListView_GetHeader(listView);

in a way to access to the header, but i don't find how to change the header height.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance, Francesco.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, there is no way to do this. You can take a look at [wxAdvTable](http://wxcode.sourceforge.net/components/advtable/) - it is a grid which allows creation of multi-line and multi-level headers for grid.

Comment: i have seen on 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/510/A-Multiline-Header-Control-Inside-a-CListCtrl?display=Print
that is possible to insert a multiline text header on list control. It's possible to embed the code used in the example in CodeProject in a wxlistctrl?

Comment: You can try to embed the header by obtaining HWND of list control and calling native WinAPI functions for embedding custom header control. Or take a look at wxListCtrl's source code and see how shows the header and do the similar thing but with your customcontrol. However this will be Windows-only solution.